# How to add correctly ApplicationUser with custom types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Let's put for example I want to add to  the `ApplicationUser` the `UserImage` class.
After setting-up an ASP.NET Core 2 project with MVC and Individual Authentication the `UserImage` addition look like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public UserImage UserImage { get; set; }
}

public class UserImage
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] UserImageBlob { get; set; }
    public string UserImageFileName { get; set; }
}
```

(the code-first migration part is done)
I setup the image acquisition in the Controllers/ManageController.cs/`Index(IndexViewModel model, IFormFile userPicture = null)`
as an `IFormFile` like:

```
var userImage = new UserImage { UserImageBlob = null, UserImageFileName = null };
if (userPicture != null && userPicture.Length > 0)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await userPicture.CopyToAsync(stream);
        userImage.UserImageBlob = stream.ToArray();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userPicture.FileName))
            userImage.UserImageFileName = userPicture.FileName;
    }
}
```

And at this point I'm stuck on how to memorize this `UserImage`.
Up to now I tried with:

```
//UserManager way:
user.UserImage = userImage;//user is given from _userManager.GetUserAsync(User)
var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user)
```

and

```
//DbContext way:
var cUser = await _context.Users
    .Include(i => i.UserImage)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == user.Id);
...
cUser.UserImage = userImage;
await TryUpdateModelAsync<ApplicationUser>(cUser, "", i => i.UserImage,/*list of other properties to update*/)
...
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Both of them always return successful result from their operations, BUT the actual `UserImage` property is never memorized in the DB(Sql Server).
I'm out of ideas on how to accomplish what I would like to.
Am I doing it wrong? How is your approach?

Comment: I believe your question is about EF code first and you should also include a tag for it. Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: I'd also suggest using a content storage for storing the image and avoid BLOB's in DB altogether. But if you're not expecting a high traffic, you can continue to use DB as your content storage which will be safe quicker to implement. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174678/why-is-it-recommended-to-store-blobs-in-separate-sql-server-tables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Answer (score 0):

Your class should look like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public long UserImageId { get; set; }
    public UserImage UserImage { get; set; }
}

public class UserImage
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] UserImageBlob { get; set; }
    public string UserImageFileName { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
}
```

This is convention based one-to-one relationship in ef-core. You can also do this with fluent API

Comment: You should add-migration then update database with ef.tools